# Issue with AWS SNSMobilePush Demo for Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am trying to work through the AWS SNSMobilePush demo (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html)  I have successfully gotten the application portion running on my android device, or appears to anyway, and I have the SNSMobilePush running, however I can't seem to get any messages... so I assume I have something configured wrong... I assume, that it is something to do with the following settings in the program:

```
public void demoAndroidAppNotification() {
    // TODO: Please fill in following values for your application. You can
    // also change the notification payload as per your preferences using
    // the method
    // com.amazonaws.sns.samples.tools.SampleMessageGenerator.getSampleAndroidMessage()
    String serverAPIKey = "<MY API KEY>";
    String applicationName = "GCMTest";  //AWS App Name
    String registrationId = "<PROJECT ID>";

    //System.out.println(Platform.GCM.name());

    snsClientWrapper.demoNotification(Platform.GCM, "", serverAPIKey,
            registrationId, applicationName, attributesMap);
}
```

I have 2 keys set up for GCM for on the Google Developer Consle 1 for android using the package name and development keystore fingerpring which I have placed in the android app.. Which runs and sits at the WELCOME SCREEN. The other is a SERVER KEY which I have placed in the  in the code above.  For the  I have placed THE REGISTRSATION ID spit out by the Android app when it registers.

The APPLICATION NAME I am using is the name of the application I created at the AWS SNS Console using the SERVER API KEY.

The TOPIC I have created at the SNS Console is named global.

The app on the android device is running, and I see Welcome, but when I run SNSMOBILEPUSH to send a message, I get no errors, but the message never reaches/appears on the device.  I assume I have something incorrect in my configuration values.. or something not set up correctly on AWS SNS, but I am not sure what I am missing.. Can anyone help?

Comment: It looks like AWS SNS is deleting my application every time I try to send a message.. .no error is visible, but after a send attempt a refresh on the SNS console shows no application... very odd.

Comment: It'll be odd if your SNS platform application is deleted by SNS. Usually a configuration issue shouldn't delete the application. One suggestion is to turn on delivery status. See https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxHTXGC8711JNF/Using-the-Delivery-Status-feature-of-Amazon-SNS